# Slow Datareader with ODP.NET

Tags: odp.net

we are using (ODP.NET) Oracle.DataAccess version 1.102.3.0 with Oracle 11g client. I am having some problems with reading data using the datareader, 
my procedure is returning  a ref_cursor around 10000 records. However fetching the data takes around 30 to 40 sec.
Are there any possibilities to improve the performace ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the FetchSize.

Since this is a Procedure and a RefCusor you can perform these operations.

- ExecuteReader
- Set the FetchSize -> do this before you start reading
- Read the Results

If you follow the above sequence of actions you will be able to obtain the size of a row.

e.g.

```
int NumberOfRowsToFetchPerRoundTrip = 2000;

var reader  =cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.FetchSize = reader.RowSize * NumberOfRowsToFetchPerRoundTrip;
while(reader.Read())
{
//Do something
}
```

This will reduce the amount of round trips. The fetch size is bytes so you could also just use an arbitrary fetchSize eg 1024*1024 (1mb). However I would recommend basing you fetch on the size of a row * the number of rows you want to fetch per request.

In addition I would set the parameters on the connection string

Enlist=false;Self Tuning=False

You seem to get more consistent performance with these settings, although there may be some variation from one version of ODP/NET to the next.